# Ruby / Rails Wait for redirect_to to resolve and do something depending on response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, zencoder, redirecttoroute

I've got a **redirect_to** in a **rails** app
that hits an endpoint to send a video to **Zencoder** to be encoded into a few different formats.

Just after I've got a **redirect_to** that redirect to a view. 
What's happening is the **redirect** to the view happens **too quickly**, so when the view makes **the first request** for the Zencoder urls - it throws **404s**.
On refresh the requests are **200**

I'd like to either:

1. Delay the redirect momentarily so that the 404's don't occcur
   (simpler)
2. Listen to the Zencoder redirect and only redirect to the view after getting a response from Zencoder

Here's the relevant code:

```
  def edit
    @director = Director.find(params[:id])
    @director_videos = Video.where(:director_id => @director.id)
    if params[:bucket].present?
      # process video
      key = params[:key]
      video = Video.new
      video.director_id = @director.id

      video.video_url = "https://"+Settings.S3_BUCKET + ".s3.amazonaws.com/" + URI.unescape(key)
      video.save    
      video.process
      redirect_to '/encode_progress' and return
    end
    @video_uploader = Video.new.video
    @video = Video.new
    redirect = "http://"+Settings.DOMAIN+"/directors/"+@director.id.to_s+"/edit"
    @video_uploader.success_action_redirect = redirect
  end
```

Comment: where is that zencoder logic in your code?

Comment: There's a route for `encode_progress` - logic is in the controller